# Mongo Upsert $in values from Find That were Not found

Tags: mongodb

I have to run mongo updates for employee id linked to a supervisorId (That's an oversimplification, but its the gist of what I need). The find uses a list of employee ids, and if the employee id is not found, I have an upsert to add the data. However the issue is I'm not getting the employee id in the upsert. Is it possible to upsert values from the $in array?

Eg:

```
db.collection.update({
 empId:{
      $in:['EMP1','EMP2','EMP3']
    }
 }, 
 {$set: {SupervisorId:'SUP25'}}, 
 {upsert:true},
 {multi:true})
```

If I run this query I get one new doc with _id and SupervisorId:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e56ece8b0ae3537d0261ghg"),
    "SupervisorId" : "SUP25"
}
```

I would like to get this in my upserts:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e56ece8b0ae3537d0261ghg"),
    "SupervisorId" : "SUP25"
    "EmpId": "EMP1"
}
```

I'm still getting comfortable with mongo, but is this even possible with an upsert? If not possible, are there any options for something similar?
MongoDB version 2.9.1

Comment: Two issues, One you need to use `.updateMany()` inorder to update multiple docs !! Your current query would update only first matching doc (You can still use update but needed to pass `{multi:true}` as an option for updating multiple docs), Another one is as far as I know you cannot upsert while using `$in` !! What is MongoDB version ?

Comment: So your MongoDB version is so old, I recommend you to upgrade it to new version asap !! Maybe with that version all you do is to fire multiple update requests/DB calls.

Comment: `empId:{$in:['EMP1','EMP2','EMP3']}}` is effectively the same as `{$or:[{empid:"EMP1"},{empid:"EMP2"},{empid:"EMP3}]}`  That only gives you a `true` if the document matches or a `false` if it doesn't.  There is no state that is passed between documents, so the executor would have no way of knowing which value to use for the upsert.